# Why do I get a cannot find local host error when trying to run asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Ive created a asp.net website in a file on my desktop, but when I run it I get cannot find local host error in the browser.  Why does this happen?  Created the site in visual studio 2010, framework 4.0

Comment: Did you install IIS on your local machine? If you ping localhost, do you get a response from 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something once and I had to change the port that the .net develpoment server was running on due to some kind of conflict (I forget the reason there was a conflict). At any rate, the answer was changing the port the dev server was running on. To do that check out this article: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/482/change-default-port-for-the-aspnet-development-server/

Comment: The article has been moved to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667443/Change-default-Port-for-the-ASP-NET-Development-Se.